# Python subprocess flush stdout

Tags: python, stdout

I have script, that should walk over all my projects (in specified folder) and call `git status`, I would like to search the returned stdout for specific keyword, to detect whether the project need some action (commit, push, merge, ...). The thing, is, the stdout is stacked from all previous calls of the current run. So the stdout for every project contains also the response from other previous projects! I am unable to flush stdout after every new call. I tried things like `proc.stdout.flush()` but it does not help. My current code is:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

from glob import glob
dirs = glob("./*/")

pointer = 0
for project in dirs:
    print("\n\n", project)
    try:
        proc = Popen(['git', 'status'], stdout=PIPE, cwd=project)
        print(proc.stdout.readlines())  
    except:
        # not a git
        pass
```

What is correct approach to flush stdout after every step, or call the Popen in "new console"?

Comment: try `print(proc.communicate()[0])`?

Comment: @Sraw Well done! You can create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: There might be more than your example code suggests, but why do you use `Popen` and `PIPE`, when what you seem to be after is [`check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to fill and process and/or print your output? Or if you needed to use the combo of the two, use `communicate` as suggested above.